# PHP Session variables not preserved on a dev copy of a working app

Tags: php, variables, session

Hello dear stackoverflowians,

I must say that this is an odd issue. Here's a little intro to what works and what doesn't.

I need to modify existing web app, so not to mess things up, I'm working on a copy. Web root directory of a copy is in the same directory as the original Web root directory. Original works just fine. Sessions are no problem, however with the copy, there's a huge problem. Sessions aren't working at all. I checked a lot of previously asked questions with the related topic but most of them were easy to solve (put session_start() at the beginning of the script).

I edited index.php file and put this code at the beginning

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  var_dump($_SESSION);
  $_SESSION["test"]=1;
  die();
```

That's a test code to see if a simple session is going to be saved. After refresh, the "test" should be inside of a session var_dump() output except it wasn't.

**Can you please give me any hints where to begin?**

```
is_writable(session_save_path()) //returns TRUE
```

I tried changing session_save_path(directory_with_777_privileges). Session files are being created. Some of them are empty, some are not. What is 100% true is that php can't access created sessions when working with copy of the original web app (or even one, index.php script).

**This did the trick:**

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'example.com', false, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'example.com', false, false);
```

So, the thing was that php.ini file was forcing php to use only secure cookies. Line above overrides that.